# How to add new CoreFont to FPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have tried to add a Font into fpdf by adding this

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4');
$pdf->AddFont('calibri','','calibri.php');
$pdf->AddFont('calibri','B','calibrib.php');
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVuSansMono','','DejaVuSansMono.php');
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVuSansMono','B','DejaVuSansMono-Bold.php');
```

If I use the font `courier`

```
$pdf->SetFont('courier', '', 10);
$pdf->Cell(0, 5, 'Hello world', 0, 1);
```

and preview the generated pdf in the browser, everything is fine.

If I use e.g. `calibri` the pdf has to be loaded twice to see the result. On first time it comes with an error like:

```
Error while loading the PDF-Document
```

If I load it again, it works and if I load it again it wont work and so on...

**What could this be?**

**Could it be that the font file is to large ?**

EDIT:

I have to say, this only appears when I call the PDF from my Preview-Script whats actually is build with jquerys ajax. Adding images to the pdf (e.g. 20MB) does not bring up this problem.

And if I preview, open up the pdf in a other tab, and go back to the first tab and load prieview again also dont brings up the problem.

Comment: Per PDF Specification, you cannot "add" Core Fonts -- they are part of the official specification ("The following 14 fonts are guaranteed to be available", something like that). You should find out how to properly *embed* your font. Since you consider its size a probable cause for the erratic behavior, you should probably embed a *subset*.

Comment: @Jongware I allready added it to the core array, but I still get this result no matter what size the font file is. 20kb is not much but still this result.